# Stored procedure execution using parameters in java using a shell script

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm new to java world and trying to learn, I'm trying to pass a stored procedure having couple of parameters as an argument to a java program that's executed via shell script, don't see the stored procedure getting executed.

Also, I have a working program that executes a stored procedure without parameters. Below are the code snippets

Storing the stored procedure as an argument like below:

```
String StProcNme = args[0];
```

Below is the code for executing the stored procedure:

```
stmt = con.createStatement();
rs = stmt.executeQuery("{call " +StProcNme+"}" );
```

In this case the stored procedure value passed to the shellscript was `TESTDB.Test_xyzz_abc_method.xxxx_req_xyz_some_test` and this is working.

When I'm trying to run the above code with stored procedure value as `TESTDB.TESTDB.Test_xyzz_abc_method.xxxx_req_xyz_some_test('TEST_MMTS_ABCXYZ','N')`, it's not working, I see the quotes around parameters are getting discarded in the program.

I'm using JDK 6 - any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this of any help? -> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-statements-callable.html

Comment: This is irrelevant to your problem, but unless your employer is forcing you, there's zero good reason to still be using Java 6 - it's literally 12 years old, and Oracle doesn't support it anymore.

Comment: Try to escape them and see if it works.

Comment: i tried escaping and did'nt work

Comment: Quotes (both singlequote ' and doublequote ") are special in Unix shells and are processed and removed by the _shell_ before Java even sees them. **Add doublequotes** around the entire value like `java myclassname "db.proc('VALUE','X')"`

Comment: It's easier to use a callableStatement, and set the parameters, so the SQL would look like TESTDB.TESTDB.Test_xyzz_abc_method.xxxx_req_xyz_some_test(?,?)

Answer (score 0):

Tried to do this in the comments, but...

```
String sqlString = args[0];
String query = "{ call " + sqlString + " }";

CallableStatement spStmt = dbConn.prepareCall(query);

for(int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
 spStmt.setObject(i+2, args[i]); // need to lookup the positioning, off the top of my head here
}

spStmt.execute();
```

And the Parameters to the script would look like:

```
myScript TESTDB.TESTDB.Test_xyzz_abc_method.xxxx_req_xyz_some_test(?,?) TEST_MMTS_ABCXYZ N
```

The only time you need to quote is if you have a non-contiguous string being passed into the shell script

```
myScript TESTDB.TESTDB.Test_xyzz_abc_method.xxxx_req_xyz_some_test(?,?) "Hello World" N
```

*** Edited to Add Shell Script ***

If you just want to get what you have working, you can create a script that tells it to pass the original command line parameters.

cmdTest bash script:

```
printf "Running Command:"
printf " %q" java CMDTest "$@"
printf "\n"

java CMDTest "$@"
```

Testing with a small java program, you get:

```
./cmdTest "TESTDB.TESTDB.Test_xyzz_abc_method.xxxx_req_xyz_some_test('TEST_MMTS_ABCXYZ','N')"
```

Output:

```
Running Command: java CMDTest TESTDB.TESTDB.Test_xyzz_abc_method.xxxx_req_xyz_some_test\(\'TEST_MMTS_ABCXYZ\'\,\'N\'\)
Arg: 0   TESTDB.TESTDB.Test_xyzz_abc_method.xxxx_req_xyz_some_test('TEST_MMTS_ABCXYZ','N')
```

The Java code for Completeness

```
public class CMDTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
          System.out.println("Arg: " + i + "\t " + args[i]);
        }
    }
}
```